# java audit log every method using aspectj

Tags: spring, aspectj

How to log messages for every method before and after the method executes. Mainly for all classes in a package whether they are managed by spring or not. Using spring aop you can intercept beans that are managed by spring, but how to intercept beans that are not managed. I don't want to use java -agent option, as it requires a jar in tomcat and other few things to be done to get it working. is compile time weaving the only choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the aspect at time of compilation.

Or you can use load time weaving, either by using the java -agent property or by using Spring LTW:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/ch07s08.html#aop-aj-ltw